# How to show textview/layout in place of empty recycleview?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I've created a fitness app where the user can save his/her `activity` and view it in `recycleview`. This works fine, but when there's no data, the `app crashes` when I try to access the `recycleview layout`.

I need to be able to show a textview("History is empty) in place of an empty `recycleview`.

Here's part of my xml `recycleview` layout.Note that this is a relative layout:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/mainbackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/HistoryTab"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="-203dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/road_run"
    tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/overlay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottom_banner"
    android:layout_below="@id/HistoryTab"
    android:background="@drawable/run_interface_background" />


<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

    android:id="@+id/Recycle_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottom_banner"
    android:layout_below="@id/HistoryTab" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/EmptyActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Your History Is Empty"
    android:textColor="#ffff"
    android:textSize="16dp" />
```

As you see if recycleview is empty, the textview EmptyActivity should be visible...ONLY when there's no data.

[image: Recyclview]

Below is the code that shows where and why the app :

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recycler_view_layout);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.Recycle_layout);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RunoraDatabaseHelper runoraDatabaseHelper = new RunoraDatabaseHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = runoraDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = runoraDatabaseHelper.RetrieveDataFromDatabase(sqLiteDatabase);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            RetrieveRunnerActivity retrieveRunnerActivity = new RetrieveRunnerActivity(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), (cursor.getString(3)));
            arrayList.add(retrieveRunnerActivity);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        runoraDatabaseHelper.close();

        adapter = new RecycleAdapter(arrayList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        returnButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.returnButton);
        history_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.history_btn);


        returnButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(DisplayHistory.this, home.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        history_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(DisplayHistory.this, settings.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

```
  Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

The line that crashes the app:

```
  RetrieveRunnerActivity retrieveRunnerActivity = new RetrieveRunnerActivity(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), (cursor.getString(3)));
```

As you can see, when no data has been saved and the database returns no data, the app crashes when I click to access the layout containing the recycleview.

Please help. I'm banging my head at this, and I've tried the answers I've seen on stackoverflow, but I'm still not having any success.

If anyone requires me to post more actvities(recycleadapater, databasehelper, RetrieveRunnerActivity class, etc), please let me know.

I've edited my code several times, but I'm not getting the desired outcome. The current code below allows me to access my recycleview activity when there's no data saved to my database to retrieve, but allows me display textview in place of an empty recycleview now, but at the same time all the buttons in that layout stop working.

When I do have data available to retrieve, recyclew_layout shows no retrieved data/items and all buttons on this activity still don't work.

```
      if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        RetrieveRunnerActivity retrieveRunnerActivity = new RetrieveRunnerActivity(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), (cursor.getString(3)));
        arrayList.add(retrieveRunnerActivity);
        EmptyActivity.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        if (cursor.getCount() <= 0) {
            recycleLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            EmptyActivity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            runoraDatabaseHelper.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer to my problem:

```
       if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            RetrieveRunnerActivity retrieveRunnerActivity = new RetrieveRunnerActivity(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), (cursor.getString(3)));
            arrayList.add(retrieveRunnerActivity);
            adapter = new RecycleAdapter(arrayList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            EmptyActivity.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        while
              (cursor.moveToNext());

    } else
        EmptyActivity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

The initial crash was actually cause by this:

```
 while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            runoraDatabaseHelper.close();
```

Hope this helps someone if they ever get into this trouble.

Answer (score 0):

the error shows your `Cursor` object has 0 record and you try to read by calling index of that empty object.

Before use `Cursor` object check the count of that by using: [Cursor.getCount()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getCount%28%29)

it return Cursor count as int variable. if there are records on your Cursor then fill your recyclerview otherwise you can show `EmptyActivity` textview that have in your xml.

Comment: Please have a look above. In my recycleadaper I have the method getItemCount. Is that not the same method as Cursor.getCount?

Comment: no thats not the same. before you create the adapter check the `Cursor.getCount`. exact below this line: `Cursor cursor = runoraDatabaseHelper.RetrieveDataFromDatabase(sqLiteDatabase);`

Comment: I've made some changes implementing cursor.getCount(), but still not winning.

Comment: It's fine I fixed it. Works the way I want it to. I'll post the answer above.

Comment: your welcome. if the answer helps to solve your problem, you can use upvote button and mark question as solved. thanks.